# OS X Application to add contact from clipboard

Tags: macos, contacts, copy-paste

Several years ago, I had a Microsoft Windows application that would offer to add a contact to Outlook if I copied it from anywhere into the clipboard. For example, if I received an email containing a person's home address, I could simply copy the address to the clipboard, then click the app sitting in the lower right of the task bar. The app would parse the address and offer to add it to Outlook as a new contact. I cannot remember the name or I would search alternativeto.net.

Is there anything like this for OS X? Something that sits in the menubar and adds contacts to the Mac Contacts application would be ideal. Now with iCloud syncing, I could easily have those addresses available on my iPhone.

Comment: Mail.app can often detect contact details in messages automatically, and if so you can directly add them to a contact or create a new card by hovering over them.

Comment: Thanks. I gave the example for an email message, but in this case, I found a postal address on the web (in Chrome) and wanted to copy/paste it to Contacts. Had to do each line separately. I looked at Services to see if there was anything, but alas, no. I tried searching the App Store but couldn't find anything that jumped out.

Comment: Chrome hasn’t implemented the system for automatic data recognition in webpages. Safari and all content-based Apple apps have it.